# How to style my react select when it is disabled (in CSS)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to make my select box either just a gray bar or invisible when it is invisible. My CSS code is working for my  elements, but I can't do the same thing for my react-select elements.
I've tried copy pasting the CSS I used for label, replacing label with "select" but nothing is happening

CSS:

```
// This is the code that makes my label elements gray boxes when disabled

label:disabled,
label[disabled] {
    background: transparent;
    border: none !important;
    font-size: 0px;
    background-color: #D8D8D8 !important;
}
```

html/js:

```
<ControlLabel className="input-label">
    Hopper Angle 
    <WithTooltip 
        tooltip={ <span>Select Hopper Angle below, or type in a custom value then click “create”.</span> }>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
    </WithTooltip>
</ControlLabel>
<br />
<CreatableSelect 
  name="hopper_angle" 
  value={{value: "hopper_angle" + this.state.hopper_angle.toString(), label: this.state.hopper_angle.toString()}}
  className="react-select"
  components={{ IndicatorSeparator }}
  options={ data["hopper_angle"].map(d => ({label: d.toString(), value: "hopper_angle" + d.toString()})) }
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  disabled={this.state.disabled_hopper}
  onCreateOption={this.handleCreateHopper}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
className={`react-select${this.state.disabled_hopper ? ' disabled-class' : ''}`}
```

In your CSS, you can add styling to `.disabled-class` (or whatever you choose to name it) that will only be applied when `this.state.disabled_hopper` is true.